# How to execute a .class file(java) from .py script?

Tags: java, python

I was doing a project on my RaspberyPi, when I stumbled onto this problem: I need a python script to run a java file, but can't find a way to do that. The files are start.py and main.class and are in the same folder.

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: I did but anything I tried to search for told me how to write my code in the python script, not how to run my file. So I had to come here to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use python to execute a bash command (assuming you're on linux), you'd use the same command to run a java file which is `java main` where `main` is `main.class`

here's a simple script that uses `subprocess` to run the command

```
import subprocess


cmd = 'java main'.split(' ')
subprocess.run(cmd)
```

Comment: According to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), there shouldn't be a reason for this not to work on Windows too (if `java` is in path).